# How to pass records from Kafka to method?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Kafka queue from where I read the data as below:

```
private static void startKafkaConsumerStream() {

        try {

            System.out.println("Print method: startKafkaConsumerStream");

            Dataset<String> lines = (Dataset<String>) _spark
                    .readStream()
                    .format("kafka")
                    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", getProperty("kafka.bootstrap.servers"))
                    .option("subscribe", HTTP_FED_VO_TOPIC)
                    .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
                    .load()
                    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
                    .as(Encoders.STRING());

            StreamingQuery query = lines.writeStream()
                    .outputMode("append")
                    .format("console")
                    .start();

            query.awaitTermination();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**The Requirement**: With the above code, I am able to print records to console however, I am jeopardized as in how do I pass these to a method which will process them.

**To do this**, I tried looking over in the documentation but could not find anything relevant. As I am a newbie to this, it might sound a bit silly. However I am stuck and would highly appreciate any hints.

**Goal of the app** The goal of the app is to accept request and send it to Kafka, then in a separate thread a Kafka reader is implemented which is responsible to read and process the request and produce the output to another Kafka queue. I am just implementing this, the architecture is not my idea.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for the explicit `append` output mode? It's the default output mode and thus I'm asking.

Comment: No earlier the tut I reffered to was set to complete I am just interested in the latest data available in Kafka (Implementing a request response pipeline)

Comment: _"a kafka reader is implemented which is responsible to read and process the request"_ <-- what exactly would you like to do in "process the request" part?

Comment: This is a MachineLearning - AI component and it is a black box for me. So I just get a handle to a method to which I have to pass the Kafka String as a method parameter.

Comment: How does this component work? Is this a function? A Java class? A REST service? How are records passed to the app? Looks like `foreach` might be the best choice so far.

Comment: Yes this is a Java Class and I have to pass my values to the process(sparkRequest req) method. Thanks for the help mate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ForeachWriter[T]` on the sink part of kafka streaming application to process each row of your query, like this:

```
   datasetOfString.write.foreach(new ForeachWriter[String] {

     def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
       // open connection
     }

     def process(record: String) = {
       // write string to connection
     }

     def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
       // close the connection
     }
   })
```

Comment: You are my Star!

Comment: Just a word for future readers: `public abstract void process(T value)
Called to process the data in the executor side. This method will be called only when open returns true.`

Answer (score 1):

`lines` is `Dataset<String>` with the values from Kafka as rows.

> how do I pass these to a method which will process them.

Depending on what exactly you'd like to do you could of course use `foreach` operator or use any other operator or function you could use for a batch Dataset.

You could use `withColumn(...)` or `select` or `map` operators.

In other words, think of Spark Structured Streaming as Spark SQL with streaming Dataset.

Comment: Thanks Jack, that is insightful am new to spark and find the documentation out there like a sea.